# CakePHP Acl confusion - denied access to group but user of that group has access

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, acl

Now I must be missing something in my ACL-controlled application.  My User model belongsTo a model called Role.  I have included the ACL behaviour in both models.  Both models have parentNode functions - in Role, this returns null.  In User, the code is below:

```
public function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)){
        return null;
    }
    if (isset($this->data['User']['role_id'])){
        $roleId = $this->data['User']['role_id'];
    } else {
        $roleId = $this->field('role_id');
    }
    if (!$roleId){
        return null;
    } else {
        return array('Role' => array('id' => $roleId));
    }
}
```

I'm logged in as a user that has role_id = 8.  In my aros table, the user has a parent_id of 9, which is the aro entry for the correct role.

I created the following action to illustrate the problem:

```
public function permissions(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if($this->Acl->check(array('model'=>'User','foreign_key'=>$this->Auth->user('id')),'Countries')){
        echo 'User: Allowed<br />';
    }else{
        echo 'User: Forbidden<br />';
    }
    if ($this->Acl->check(array('model'=>'Role','foreign_key'=>$this->Auth->user('role_id')),'Countries')){
        echo 'Role: Allowed';
    }else{
        echo 'Role: Forbidden';
    }
}
```

When I run the action, I get:

```
User: Allowed
Role: Forbidden
```

The user entry does not have any entries in the aros_acos table.  The only entries in that table are for Role aros.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks.

Edit - just in case it's not clear, the expected behaviour would be that both the user and the role are forbidden from accessing this controller ('Countries').

Edit - I do assign permissions, like so:

```
    $this->Acl->deny('City admin','Countries');
```

I've verified in the database that this has worked.

Comment: Where do you assign the permissions? Have you checked the cookbook about setting up permissions?

Comment: If you shed some light on my questions maybe I can give you a hand

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna go out on a limb here since you haven't answered my question. Have you checked [this?](http://book.cakephp.org/view/648/Setting-up-permissions)

Can't really tell since you don't show it, but you should set up your permissions and allowed actions in the manner specified in that link.

Comment: Thanks, I do assign my permissions, edited my question to include this.

Comment: Change 'Countries' in your deny to controllers/Countries